# Load Markers from a database MySQL on Google Maps v3

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, json, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to send some markers info to a database, the markers are saving in database successful,

But I cant take the data to a page that load the markers, I think thats a problem on programming, or calling the markers to they positions

I will post the link of my examples, and them the programming.

This is my code of index.html

Thanks guys =), waiting one answer, I dont have any idea how to solve it

EDIT: I forgot to say, if you click on the map it create a marker, and if you click on this marker you can edit it informations.

Comment: nitpick: you don't "sent to a sql". sql is just a language. You send "to a database".

Comment: Ops, miss, thanks guy, corrected

Comment: I think thats my error is when I'm calling de database info to my loady.html, or how i'm calling the line  position: (latlng). Can someone see please ? =)

Comment: Are you getting any PHP errors? I tried to look at it on my phone and saw a blank page.

Comment: No problems on PHP, it dosn't open on www =). When have some error, it show the line of the error on the PHP page.

Comment: Can someone help ? I'm waiting for one week

Comment: Where is the code that retrieves the marker data from the database? The "fetch1" branch of `phpsqlinfo_addrow.php`, despite its name, inserts new data. Also, the `adicionaMarker()` function does not accept parameters, I guess it's missing `latlng`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem may be with your latlng variable. Not sure if the getposition method returns the correct format. Try var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(marker.getPostion().lat(), marker.getPosition().lng());